# async Producer-Consumer application with concurrent scheduler

Tags: c#, .net, semaphore, tpl-dataflow

I was implementing a Producer-Consumer using `BufferBlock`. The code is working well.

```
static async Task Produce(ITargetBlock<int> queue)
{
    try
    {
        // Post messages to the block asynchronously. 
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending: {0}", i);
            await queue.SendAsync(i);
        }
    }
    finally 
    {
        queue.Complete();
    }
}

static async Task Consume(ISourceBlock<int> queue)
{
    // Read messages from the block asynchronously. 
    while (await queue.OutputAvailableAsync())
    {
        int value = await queue.ReceiveAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Receiving: {0}", value);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Create a BufferBlock<int> object. 
    var queue = new BufferBlock<int>();

    try
    {
        var produce = Produce(queue);
        var consume = Consume(queue);

        Task.WaitAll(produce, consume, queue.Completion);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An exception was thrown: {0}", exception.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Terminating...");
    }
}
```

Now I have a throttling issue, which is I want to the maximum concurrent number for consumer is 4. I want to use `SemaphoreSlim` bot not sure how to apply it.

Notice: it is a concurrent scheduler question, not parallelism problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "concurrent number for consumer"?

Comment: Say at any time we can't consume more than 4 items.

Comment: @Love: Why don't you just use `ActionBlock` with a limited concurrency of 4?

Comment: @StephenCleary, I had a hard time to understand `ActionBlock`. I thought it is for parallelism instead of concurrentcy. Parallelism  is for multiple cpu cores.

Comment: @Love Is there any reason using the available cores is undesirable?

Comment: @Gusdor, my application is a telephony application. There are many ports. We can only take call when ports are available. It may have 100 ports, so it means we can take maximum 100 calls at any time. If we use MaxDegreeOfParallelism,can we set it as 100 in this case?

Comment: @Love: TPL Dataflow can handle either parallel or asynchronous work. `ActionBlock` should work fine.

Comment: @StephenCleary, any link for `ActionBlock` plus asynchronous and throttling?

Comment: @Love: I'm not sure what you mean. [Like this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @StephenCleary, yes. It is. I have checked up your blog but not found such an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is to be able to consume a certain amount at a time you can simply call `TryRecieve` multiple times until it's empty, or the amount was reached. Here's an extension method that handles that:

```
public static bool TryReceive<T>(this BufferBlock<T> bufferBlock, int count, out IList<T> items)
{
    items = new List<T>();   
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        T item;
        if (bufferBlock.TryReceive(out item))
        {
            items.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return items.Any();
}
```

And so the consumer becomes:

```
static async Task Consume(BufferBlock<int> queue)
{
    // Read messages from the block asynchronously. 
    while (await queue.OutputAvailableAsync())
    {
        IList<int> values;
        queue.TryReceive(4, out values);
        Console.WriteLine("Receiving: {0}", string.Join(", ", values));
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of errors. "No overload for method 'TryReceive' takes 2 arguments. And IList does not contain a definition for 'Any' ....

Comment: @Love The extension method in my answer takes 2 arguments (on top of the bufferBlock it extends). Any is part of the System.Linq namespace.

Comment: So I need to put it in a separate class instead of a method? It is the meaning of the extension?

Comment: @Love yes. Extension methods need to be inside a static class.

Comment: I put it in a separate class. Now the error is `Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.ISourceBlock<int>' to 'Sysyem.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.BufferBlock<int>'`

Comment: @Love Change your `consume` method to accept a `BufferBlock`.